# Cursor change(like ms paint color picker)in .svg file

Tags: html, svg

I have created a code of .svg file to change the color of car by color picker, i want to change the cursor like ms paint`s color picker if i changing the color of the car..!

Comment: create a foreignObject element and stick `<input type="color"... ` in it.

Answer (score 1):

First read about [**cursor**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) css property - there is no default dropper cursor (like in MS Paint).

But you can create custom cursor, see [example](http://jsbin.com/venetonuko/2/edit?html,css,output):

You can embed custom cursor right into your css (like in example) or use custom ico-file on server side.